# Boolean combinatorics c++

Tags: c++, binary, boolean, combinatorics, boolean-logic

I'm trying to do a combinatorics-type problem: finding how many different variable settings of a boolean formula will evaluate to true. My initial thought is by generating each possible binary number of length n (n being number of variables in the problem). For the function x1 OR x2, then n=2, so possibilities are:
00, 01, 10, 11. My original idea was to go from 0 to (n*n)-1 and use bitset to translate each number to binary. My problem is that the length of a bitset must be determined by runtime, so no bitset(i), like I was planning on doing, where n is the number of variables and i is at each iteration. I can't do dynamic bitset either, because my school hasn't installed boost libraries. So now I'm wondering if I should numerically translate each number manually... or if there's a better solution altogether, as I imagine this solution I'm suggesting is computationally expensive with large numbers. Is there a way to treat this like a combinatorics problem so that I can run through in n^2 time and find each possible boolean setting of length n, without translating each number to binary?

Comment: If you do solve it in `O(n^2)` please post your solution, it would make things so much simplier! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Answer (score 0):

The direct formula formed for this is **4<sup>n</sup>-2<sup>n</sup>** 
**Explanation**
For a n bit number, total possible combinations are 4<sup>n</sup>. And for **a XOR b** to be true at least one of their bit should be different. 
For the bits of a and b at a position there are 4 possibilities(00,01,11,10), out of this 11,00 are the cases where both bits are same. Now we find number of combinations such that all bots at a position are same in both numbers(ie, a XOR  b is false). this is equal to 2<sup>n</sup>   
So, the requires combinations are **4<sup>n</sup>-2<sup>n</sup>**